# How does playgif.com work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gif, animated-gif

[playgif](http://playgif.com) adds functionality to animated gifs, including controls for pause, reverse, and speed adjustment.  I would like to do this with animated gifs on my site.  Any ideas how this is done and if it's possible to create a solution in javascript and/or python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the page source.  All the code is there, unobfuscated.

Looks like the image is split into the individual frames as separate images, then the javascript simply toggles which one is visible.  I'm guessing the server splits the GIF using some standard image library, which the page's javascript then uses.